# corda release 13 kyro exception for Java.util.Date field in my model class

Tags: corda

com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Class java.util.Date is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization.

Class java.util.Date is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization

My Model Object having Date property/field , so i am getting this error 
I am using Corda RElease 13 version.

AS in corda release 13 version we dont have overriden method customizeSerialization(SerializationCustomization kryo) {
}
in Plugin Class so , Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark classes as serializable using the `@CordaSerializable` annotation.

Also, note that you can still use `customizeSerialization` - this plugin method isn't deprecated.

Comment: Thanks .. joel.. :)

Comment: Hello. I have a state say StateX which have a field which is date. I marked the StateX as @CordaSerializable. Still I am getting the same error